# Intellij find in path not working for public/scripts in react project

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

I have a react project and the intellij shows the public/scripts as a different color. When I search word in project, it doesn't search from files in public/scripts.

See figure: I want to search `syncHistoryWithStore`, it only displays four occurrences in appSpec.js, but apparently I have this word in app.js.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red color means that the `public/scripts` folder is [excluded](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#project_tool_window) from project (navigation, search, indexing). If you select scope: `Project` IDE does not perform search inside it. Try selecting the scope to `Directory` ans select this folder directory. Then text search should work even on excluded folder.

Comment: Find in Directory works now. Is there a way to include public/scripts to my project? Since I would like search in project.

Comment: Try un-mark it as excluded from context menu as shown here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#project_tool_window.

Comment: I also noticed sometimes it doesnt work when `$` sign is next to a word , say a PHP variable. Because it enables regex in find popup sometimes. I got it working after enabling and disabling that Regex checkbox in the same popup